# Unable to edit Record with validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

We have below lead status on Lead object

Lead Status Pick values : New, New Response, In Progress, Rejected, Qualified

We wanted to restict users from switching status and editing records

1. When New or New Response status, user should not be able to edit any record/field on Lead until the status changes to Inprogress
2. When the status is Inprogress, user can only change it to rejected or qualified. But can edit record with Inprogress status

Below is the validation rule I tried.
The problem is with InProgress status, its does not allow users to update any other field/record value. It only allows user to update and save with rejected or qualified status.

Can someone pls help, on how can we allow user to edit record/fields in Inprogess with the same validation rule below.

```
AND(
 ($Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'),
 IF(
 AND(
 OR(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( Status ),"New"),
    (ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( Status ),"New Response"))),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status ,"In Progress"))),
    true,
    IF(
    AND(
    (ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( Status ),"In Progress")),
    AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status ,"Qualified")),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status ,"Rejected"))
)),true,false)  
    )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one: (Skipped the Admin exception)

```
OR(
    AND(
        NOT(ISNEW()),
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL( Status ,"New"),
            ISPICKVAL( Status ,"New Response")
        )
    ),
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( Status) ,"In Progress"),
        AND(
            Not(ISPICKVAL(Status ,"Qualified")),
            Not(ISPICKVAL(Status ,"Rejected"))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I tried the above but its not allowing the create a new or new response lead

Comment: You are right. I edited the formula for this.